# Legal status concerning about payment

Tags: legal-status, payment

I am looking for the patent WO2004007523=TWI333957;
however, I do not see TWI333957 listed on the Google patent.
My question is: is it because of non-payment of fee of the patent in TW, TWI333957 removed from google patent search? 
Thank you.
[image: Search by WO number]
[image: Espacenet result]
[image: Legal status]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Patent search does not include Taiwan patents now, therefore it has nothing to do with legal status of said patent.

Currently Google search covers United States, Europe, International (WIPO), China, Germany and Canada.

hope it answers your query.

Comment: sure you can ask

Comment: Based on the statement "annulment or lapse of patent due to non-payment of fees", if a company wants to patent similar invention do they still need to provide non-infringement statement to design around that patent? Thank you!

Comment: See, patent and infringement are separate issues. For patenting you are required only to show novelty, non-obviousness and sometime industrial use. For using the invention since the patent is lapsed dont worry for Taiwan.

Comment: Got it! Because one of my clients wants to apply for the patent of this active ingredient in Taiwan and they show us the result found on Espacenet, they don't need to worry about the IP issue right?

Comment: with this patent you dont have to worry, but i advise you to check if other patents cover the products client is interested in.